# Rails and whitelist paramaters when using form_with without model,

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

Here is my  stuation, rails 6, I m trying to impliment Mail Controller for "contact us" page  and it's traight forward, route, controlerand call the mailer controller, all works, I reacieve the email, except  getting the params from the view to mailer and  when white listing the params, here "name" I get an error for the token.

```
#route
  get "/contact-us", to: 'home#contact', as: 'home_contact' 
  post "/contact-us", to: 'home#contact_send_email', as: 'home_contact_send_email' 
##############################
#controller page 
...
 def contact
 end

def contact_send_email # POST Method 

UserMailer.with(contact_params).contact_email.deliver_later
    redirect_to( home_contact_path)
  end   
private
def contact_params
      params.permit(:name) 
end
...
#################################
# view # home >contact.html.erb

...
<%= form_with( url:  home_contact_send_email_path, method: "post") do |form| %>
<%= form.label :name, class:"label" %>
<%= form.text_field :name, class:" field input is-medium"%>
...

##################################
console puts this error :
Unpermitted parameters: :authenticity_token
```

- I tried using: params.require(:home).permit(:name) but I got the params for home are empty.

My question, is it possible, without creating any model, **to whitelist paramaters when using form_with url,** how can I do that ? if not is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with the message (it's not an error).

I guess your params hash looks something like:

```
{
  name: 'some_name',
  controller: 'home',
  action: 'contact_send_mail',
  authenticity_token: '............'
}
```

So your contact_params is sending a 'hash-like' object with the `name` permitted and the `authenticity_token` not permitted. The message you see makes sense since you are passing a hash with an unpermitted key.

I mean, there's no error, you say it works, and the message you see means that strong parameters are actually working as intended (you are passing more keys than the expected ones and it tells you that).

Comment: Thanks Ariel.
You are right: parameters looks like that :
`{"authenticity_token"=>"BcG/fzU/nIj34BIcz2y2XlnQfVCK1ZIl/dj5e9BbPjxUgMDyrqHPI8I4DnPE4RGkGt3+5MmojwJtAkH4U5ibjA==", "name"=>"name",  "commit"=>"send!", "controller"=>"home", "action"=>"contact_send_email"} `
Just tokens are to reinforce security,  and I was worried about the worst case senario...to get hacked or spamed, I dont know much about that!

Answer (score 0):

Add a :scope to your form_with call; it can be anything you want.  This will give rails a key to put the form's params inside.  That will then allow you to use the ordinary `params.require(:my_scope).permit(:param_a, :param_b, :etc)` flow.

I'll use `contact` as the scope in this example, but you can use anything:

```
<%= form_with(url: home_contact_send_email_path, scope: :contact, method: "post") do |form| %>
  <%= form.label :name, class:"label" %>
  <%= form.text_field :name, class:" field input is-medium"%>
```

Then in the controller:

```rb
def contact_params
  params.require(:contact).permit(:name)
end
```

*To ignore the warning is to move slowly down the path to a less clean and harder to maintain codebase.*  It's intended to warn you in development as a security precaution.  However it can be configured via: [config.action_controller.action_on_unpermitted_parameters](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#config-action-controller-action-on-unpermitted-parameters)